# Apt-get ignoring a repo even if I clear the cache

Tags: ppa, apt, repository, cache

I'm trying to get the ubuntugis repo to install on a server and I keep getting the line:

```
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu/ lucid/main Translation-en_GB
```

when I do an apt-get update.

This is not correct behaviour. I have cleared the folders /var/cache/apt/ and /var/lib/apt/lists/ so that I can be sure apt-cache shouldn't be using its local cache but I still have that repo ignored when updating.

Can someone please tell me what to do to try and troubleshoot this? I don't really understand what is wrong and don't know where to go from here to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 2):

The "Ign" just means that there is nothing new from the repo that needs downloading and you're up to date.